# Inserting Items in gridview to Left Side also scrolls gridview to Left

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

In my windows 8 metro app , I am using GridView (horizontal scrolling),according to One of the requirements from client , I need to INSERT items (adding items from top side in observable collection) into this gridview so that GridView's scroll do not scroll to the left but it's scroll bar shows that some items have been added to the left side in gridview(scroll bar shrinks according to the number of items added).

Whats happening right now is ( considering GridView's horizontal offset is 0.0)   whenever I INSERT items into gridview's binded ObservableCollection, it add gridviewitems to the left of the current position of gridview and instead of increasing horizontal offset it actually jumps to the 0 horizontal offset again which is not the requirement. How can I stop this jump of gridview when I insert items to the left side? Same like it behaves when new items are added to the end of observable collection , it does not jumps to the right end.

Hope so I have explained the situation , Please help and let me know if anything does not makes sense.

Comment: Yikes, that's a tricky one. But a common requirement. I look forward to the answer. I will try to work out a solution in the meanwhile. I imagine the answer will be to scroll an item into view, but you want it to happen without a jump.

Comment: Hey @Jerry Nixon - MSFT ,   I almost solved this issue, What I have done is following :

As I know how many items was added(inserted) to top of Collection , 1- I just calculated SCROLL effect for one Item move and 

2- multiplied it with with the number of items added to the top.

3- then used    scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(...calculation result)

and it solved the issue,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I almost solved this issue, What I have done is following :

As I know how many items was added(inserted) to top of Collection ,

> 1. I just calculated SCROLL effect for one Item move using item's width
> 2. multiplied it with with the number of items added to the top.
> 3. then used scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(...calculation result)

and it solved the issue

Comment: Does your GridView row count change with screen resolution change? If so, how do you calculate the horizontal impact of a new item?

Comment: Remember that ScrollToHorizontalOffset is deprecated in favor of CHangeView on the ScrollViewer. You prob already found that.

Comment: I will post here link of example App when I will finished my current project, (I am on very tight deadline)

The gridview is an infinite gridview that expands in both directions while scrolling left or right , just think of a Grid view showing Dates , when scrolls to right/left it adds more dates to both sides so not changing  gridview row count (Actually there is just one ROW in main gridview [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kcfcs.png))

Yes I know that about ChangeView but I think it's available for 8.1? I am using windows 8.